# Using field calculator to auto-increment within a range?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I am trying to use field calculator to number points between -700 and 700. I have used this code block:

```
rec=0 
def autoIncrement(): 
  global rec 
  pStart = 700
  pInterval = -1 
  if (rec == 0):  
   rec = pStart   
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
return rec
```

which works great, but only numbers between 700 and 0, but I would like it to number all the way to -700 before starting over. Is this possible with this approach or do I need to try a different method?

Comment: Try divmod or % operator on autoincremented value and 1400-result

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this - I'm not sure I understand what you mean by this, could you explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have 1401 points to number and you are trying to autodecrement, try the code below:

```
rec=-700 
def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart = 700 
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == -700):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec -= pInterval  
 return rec
```

I should say though, this is an easy fix, not a proper solution to your problem or possible derivatives!

Comment: This did what I needed and was more 'proper' than the clunky temporary solution I came up with. Thanks!